# ASP.net timer when logged out and multiple logins

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I am new to asp.net and programming in general.
I Have two questions,

1. How can i make a timer count even if my website is closed? login later, and see it still counting?
2. What is the best / good way of making a website handle multiple logins, without making a separate page for each username from a database? 
   I need the timer from question one, to be independent of which username was used to login.

Tried to google my questions, but I'm not sure what it's called, and its hard to explain.

Comment: What do you mean by "handle multiple logins"? Are you referring to supporting multiple users in general? Supporting multiple simultaneous users specifically? What do you mean by "making a separate page for each username"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i will try to explain with an example.

Bob logs inn to my website, starts a timer, logs out, comes back 6 hours later, logs inn, stops the timer, and it updates to a database.
Meanwhile, Jack and Gill have also logged in at different times, and have their own timer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 1: You cannot rely on `Timer` instances working in ASP.NET: IIS will kill your Application Pool processes as its needs dictate - such as if your website hasn't received any visitors in a 90-minute window, if your pool process becomes unresponsive, to reduce memory load, and on a regular basis (every 1740 minutes by default). For this reason `Timer` instances in ASP.NET cannot be depended upon to ensure code is regularly called.

Instead your webhost should be providing you with a "cron job" or scheduled-task facility that allows a HTTP request to be sent to your website on a regular basis which you could use to begin a periodic task, alternatively there are external, third-party, services like Pingdom and IPPatrol which do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, i will research Pingdom and IPPatrol, as I am not ready to pay for any decent webhost until my website is complete.

So I can continue using "Timer" if I implement Pingdom or IPPatrol?
my timer will be ticking once a minute, and could be going for 12 hours+ without any activity in the meantime